# Magento Paypal Payment Standard not displaying as option in Checkout Page

Tags: magento, paypal, checkout

I am using Paypal Website Payment Standard in Magento and Enabled it as Sandbox for testing.

My Base Currency, Default Display Currency and Allowed Currencies are set to Philippine Peso which i set in System -> Configuration -> Currency Setup since we are Philippine Based seller.

The problem is if set the Currencies  to Philippine Peso, the paypal payment is not displaying as option in checkout page. If I set the currency to US Dollar, the paypal payment option will then appear.

What do you think is the problem? Do you think this is because Philippine is not approved by Paypal?

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For those having the same problem, it could be that the currency code is not supported in Magento Paypal.

I solved my problem using this :

Create the file Config.php in /app/code/local/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php

Step 1

Copy the file from /app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php to /app/code/local/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php

Step 2

Look for the $_supportedCurrencyCodes

```
protected $_supportedCurrencyCodes = array('AUD', 'CAD', 'CZK', 'DKK', 'EUR', 'HKD', 'HUF', 'ILS', 'JPY', 'MXN',
    'NOK', 'NZD', 'PLN', 'GBP', 'SGD', 'SEK', 'CHF', 'USD', 'TWD', 'THB');
```

and add your currency that needs supporting to the end of the array

```
protected $_supportedCurrencyCodes = array('AUD', 'CAD', 'CZK', 'DKK', 'EUR', 'HKD', 'HUF', 'ILS', 'JPY', 'MXN',
    'NOK', 'NZD', 'PLN', 'GBP', 'SGD', 'SEK', 'CHF', 'USD', 'TWD', 'THB', 'PHP');
```

Source : http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/payment/tweak_paypal_standard_for_non-supported_base_currency

Works for my country Philippines (PHP)

Comment: Good find kabayan! I will look into this one.